# Laravel Mail queue different than Mail send

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send mails using simple DB queue driver. Queue works fine, but problem is with mail content. When I'm sending email with send() method all is fine. Content is like it should be, but when trying to use queue, content is not as should be, I get content from 2nd line of this code (but content is changed after second line before queueing mail):

```
        $mail->textPlain = strip_tags($request->content);
    $mail->textHtml = base64_encode($request->content);
    $mail->date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $mail->save();

    //This mail content will be sent
    $thread = $this->getThread($ticket, $request->content);
    $mail->textPlain = strip_tags($thread);
    $mail->textHtml = base64_encode($thread);

    Email::to($ticket->from)->queue(new Reply($mail));
```

That part where I'm appending $mail object is not shown in final message when using queues, final message is - `$mail->textHtml = base64_encode($request->content);`. 
But should be - 
`$thread = $this->getThread($ticket, $request->content);
$mail->textPlain = strip_tags($thread);
$mail->textHtml = base64_encode($thread);`

$mail is object from Mail model.

Process: I'm storing in DB just last reply from input, but final reply message delivered to recipient is all messages in thread.

reply.blade.php

```
{!! base64_decode($reply->textHtml) !!}
```

Comment: when models are queued, basically only an identifier is stored, when the job is processed it gets reloaded from the database .. anything that wasn't persisted wont be there when its retrieved

Comment: So I can queue only saved model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the job gets serialized, the Model instances aren't serialized as a representation of the current object. There is basically an identifier stored which is used to retrieve the Model instance from the database when the job is unserialized. (class type, id value to query for, loaded relationships, roughly)

Anything that isn't persisted wont be available when the model is retrieved from the database.

`Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels` -> `Illuminate\Queue\SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers`

If you need other information, you can have more variables passed to the Job when created.